# I have to automate such that my appium code opens each and every contact present in my whatsapp account

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium, whatsapp

But currently what happens is it just opens the contacts present in the first page of contacts list and unable to scroll down to other contacts so in short it just opens the contacts present on the first page. How can i make my code to scroll down to each contact and click on it?

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
//import static org.testng.AssertJUnit.assertEquals;
//import java.awt.List;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.SwipeElementDirection;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
//import objectRepository.HomePageElements;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidKeyCode;



    public class watsappjunit {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        AndroidDriver driver;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Before
    public void Before() throws Exception {
    // HomePageElements hpee= new HomePageElements(driver);

     File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
     File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "/Apps/Amazon/");
     File app = new File(appDir, "com.whatsapp_v2.16.155-451245_Android-  2.1.apk");

     DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
     capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
     capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Redmi Note 3");
     capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.0.1");
     capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
     capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
     capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.whatsapp");

     AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Thread.sleep(2000); 

        // To open the contacts tab in Watsapp
        WebElement phno = driver.findElementByName("CONTACTS");
        phno.click();

        List<WebElement> chatName = driver.findElements(By.id("com.whatsapp:id/contactpicker_row_name"));
        System.out.println("Total Chats in your WhatsApp are - "+ chatName.size());

        // To iterate over the elements
       for (WebElement names : chatName) {
            // To print the Chat Names
            System.out.println(names.getText());
            // To click on each chat
            names.click();

            // To press back button in Android
            driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.BACK);
            driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.BACK);
        }

        driver.quit();
    }


    }
```

Comment: The link to code: {https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KuC_e2lVvMst3Yvko1NLUUUELAE-LKxJBjr6aCA_8IU/edit}

Answer (score 0):

You can open uiautomatorviewer.bat which located in your Android Home//tools folder, use that tool to catch your simulator screen, then you'll be get the screen elements' attribute through that tool.

After that, you'll be able to write down your automation code.

Comment: Yes that is what I am doing but the thing is after the first 7 contacts which are visible when we open whatsapp my code does not go down to the rest of the other contacts in my watsapp account

Answer (score 0):

It depends which Appium's version you are using. In older versions you could use driver.ScrollTo("name of element").  But in newer version you sould use TouchAction class in order to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use swipe method with constant start x and end x with variable start y and end y to scroll down after you open first list of elements 
Den again scroll down , view contracts , scroll till u need